# com_error: (-2147352567, 'exception occurred.', (0, none, none, none, 0, -2147352565), none)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, win32com, xlwings

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'exception occurred.', (0, none, none, none, 0, -2147352565), none)

how to solve this error? we are using excel protected file and trying to connect with dataframe in pandas python

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import time
PATH = r"C:\Users\Shaileshbhai\Desktop\Lakhan\dummy.xlsx"
wb = xw.Book(PATH)
sheet = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

df1 = sheet.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
df1

def timer():
    time.sleep(5)
    df1 = sheet.used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
    print(df1)
    print("****************")
    timer()
timer()
```

Comment: @James Z ..I'm not getting your answer...please help me

Comment: Try opening with a password; `wb = xw.Book(PATH, password=password)` And @James Z just edited your question, he did not provide an answer or comment.

Comment: @moken ok....Tried...but still not working ...it shows com error

Comment: What protection does the workbook/worksheet have?

Comment: I am using Excel file....and give password

Comment: @moken Basically I got com error while using win32 and xlwing library....my aim is to get dataframe from that Excel protected file

Comment: If the file is a standard Excel with password on open, then including the password on opening the workbook as shown should be all that's needed. It that is comming up with an error then it seems there is a problem with the workbook or someother issue accessing it. Try a test with a new workbook (enable password) and confirm you can open the workbook as shown.

Comment: @moken already done same thing.  But not working....then i have changed System....then it's working but why it's not working in my system?